# Reversing a regular transformation matrix

Tags: matrices

I'm working in 2D, with 3x3 matrices.

I have an object at position T.
I want to rotate/scale around the origin.

- Origin position **O**
- Rotation **R**
- Scale **S**
- Origin position **P**

To find my matrix, I would normally do this:

1. Translate by **O**
2. Rotate by **R**
3. Scale by **S**
4. Translate by **-O**
5. Translate by **P**

Except for the problem I'm working on right now, I need to construct the same transformation matrix, but I don't have the original position **O**.

Instead, I have the final position (after the scale and rotation) of the object, **O'**.

I'm not really sure how to tackle this. My gut tells me it's probably very simple, but it's been hounding me for almost an entire day now.

Comment: I don't understand how you're working with $3\times3$ matrices in 2 dimensions.

Comment: The wording may have been a little unclear, sorry. I'm working in an object in two-dimensional space with 3x3 matrices. A 2D-geometry transformation matrix requires 3x3 matrices, there's an explanation here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10698962/why-do-2d-transformations-need-3x3-matrices